# Как растянуть изображение в кнопке

Tags: c#, winforms

Сделал вот такую не замысловатую конструкцию:
Но не получается сделать, чтобы фотка, которая будет помещена в ImageButtom могла выбирать размеры такие как вот имеет: **BackgroundImage**
Помогите сделать...

```
private Image _image;
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
 if (_image != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, (Width / 2) - (_image.Width / 2), (Height / 2) - (_image.Height / 2));
            }
public Image ImageButtom
        {
            get
            {
                return _image;
            }
            set
            {
                _image = value;
                RecreateHandle();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Stretch
e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, this.ClientRectangle);
    
        
// Center
int left = (this.ClientSize.Width - _image.Width) / 2;
int top = (this.ClientSize.Height - _image.Height) / 2;
e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, left, top);
    
        
// Tile
using (var texture = new TextureBrush(_image)) {
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(texture, this.ClientRectangle);
}

           
// Zoom
double xr = (double)this.ClientSize.Width / _image.Width ;
double yr = (double)this.ClientSize.Height / _image.Height;
Rectangle rect = this.ClientRectangle;
if (xr > yr) {
    rect.Width = (int)(_image.Width * yr);
    rect.X = (this.ClientSize.Width - rect.Width) / 2;
} else {
    rect.Height = (int)(_image.Height * xr);
    rect.Y = (this.ClientSize.Height - rect.Height) / 2;
}
e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, rect);
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, можно ли у вас попросить конструкцию по выбору одного из этих пунктов

Comment: @СергейМаерович, нужно сделать у класса свойство, имеющее тип перечисления `ImageLayout`, а в метод `OnPaint` добавить оператор `switch`, проверяющий значение этого свойства, c вариантами: `case ImageLayout.Stretch:`, `case ImageLayout.Center:` и т. д.